# Timeout waiting for connection from the pool on S3 bucket listing

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I need to list all the files in the S3 bucket using aws-java-sdk. The size of the files in the directory I'm listing is around 160 GB. So while listing I get this error:

```
SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Timeout waiting for connection from the pool
```

I tried to use close on the S3 object but the problem is that I perform other operations on listed files like get and put after list. Therefore, when I call close after listing I get an error like: can't perform an operation on a closed object.
How can I improve the mechanism for listing to avoid errors and be able to read all the files?

Here's a current implementation:

```
    def listFSObjects(path: String) = {
    val builder = ListObjectsV2Request
      .builder
      .bucket(bucketName)

    val listObjectsV2Request = builder.build()
    val listObjectsV2Response: ListObjectsV2Iterable = awsS3Client
      .listObjectsV2Paginator(listObjectsV2Request)
    listObjectsV2Response
}

    def list(path: String): List[String] = listFSObjects(path).map(_.path)
    
      def getObject(fromFullPath: String): ResponseInputStream[GetObjectResponse] = {
        val pathRegex(fromBucket, fromKey) = fromFullPath
        logger.info(s"fromBucket $fromBucket, fromFullPath $fromFullPath")
        val getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest
          .builder()
          .bucket(fromBucket)
          .key(fromKey)
          .build()
        awsS3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest)
      }
    
      def execute() = {
         val listSource = list(fromBucket).filter(_.endsWith("csv.gz"))
         val downloadedFiles = listSource.map(file => getObject(file))
         ...
      }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS SDK but the error sounds like you open many connections but never release them. Either close them systematically and ask for a new one when you need to perform a new operation. And/or consider increasing the pool size if it's too small and you're doing many things in parallel.

Comment: @GaëlJ do you what is the way to increase pool size? I wasn't able to find anything on this version of the aws-java-sdk